# getting GtkTressStore parent from child in python

Tags: python, gtk

I've got this hierarchy in GTKTreeView

```
-Title
---Header
------numbers a
------numbers b
------numbers c
```

when I click on a number I want to print out the header

To get the parent of a child I use something like

```
number_parent=GtkTreeStore.get_iter_first()
model=GTKTreeView.get_model()
parent=model.get_value(number_parent,0)
```

but this just prints out the Title and not the Header.

I tried

```
value=GtkTreeStore.get_iter(path)
 GtkTreeStore.get_value(value,0)
```

where path is a tuple eg (0:0:3)

but this just prints out the number.

Is there a way for me to get the Header?

Comment: From the model you have described it looks like `Header` is a child of `Title` and the first iter will point to the `Title`. What does `model.get_value(model.iter_children(number_parent), 0)` give you?

Comment: ok, I tried your method another.anon.crowd at it works. but if i have say header 1 and header 2. it only prints out header 1, even if i click on the children of header 2.

Comment: Yes that is the expected outcome. When you get the first iter, you will get `Title`. Now `Title` will have children `Header1`, `Header2` etc (assuming the above structure you have mentioned repeats). You have to traverse the list of the children by calling `iter_next` to get other `Headers#`. If you have the path you can convert it to string and remove the last entry to get the path of the parent i.e. clear until `:` in reverse eg. `0:0:1` -> `0:0`, `1:2:3` -> `1:2`. You can get iter from string which will give the required `Header#`. Btw where are you doing all this? In some signal callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got the solution with thanks to another.anon.coward

I decided to use the get_path method.

```
path=GtkTreeStore.get_path(name)
path_value=str(path)
```

I found that string slicing path directly did not work.

```
number_title_path=GtkTreeStore.get_iter(path_value[:1])
number_header_path=GtkTreeStore.get_iter(path_value[:3])
number_path=GtkTreeStore.get_iter(path_value)
```

Setting model

```
model=GtkTreeView.get_model()
number_title=model.get_value(number_title_path,0)
number_header=model.get_value(number_header_path,0)
number=model.get_value(number_path,0)
```

This is all done in 'on_treeview1_button_press_event' signal event.

So when I click on number, I get back the title and the header.